# QT get jpeg exif metadata for DateTime

Tags: c++, qt, jpeg, qt-creator, exif

I want to get the EXIF metadata of my JPEG images (only DateTime).
I want to use the standard Qt functions if possible. I use Qt Creator on Windows.

I tried to use `QMediaMetaData::DateTimeOriginal()` but I don't know how to use it. So I can't compile it. I didn't find any examples for images.

My attempt:

```
QString info;
info = QMediaMetaData::DateTimeOriginal(PathtoImageFile);
```

The error message is:

```
...mainwindow.cpp:80: Fehler: no match for call to '(const QString) (QString&)'
             info = QMediaMetaData::DateTimeOriginal(PathtoImageFile);
                                                              ^
```

What am I doing wrong, and what's the correct way to obtain this metadata?

Note: I have ensured that the multimedia library is included/linked:

```make
QT += multimedia
```

Comment: Add `QT += multimedia` to your .pro file and try compiling again.

Comment: thanks, changed @TobySpeight

Comment: I'm not sure if this was solved using Qt? If so, please post the solution. In the meantime I can comment that I have used the lightweight [easyexif](https://github.com/mayanklahiri/easyexif) library for this. But I'm really looking for Qt native solution too, in particular one that can also overwrite the date-time infromation the Exif data of an existing photo.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation shows that `QMediaMetaData::DateTimeOriginal` isn't a method; it's a string constant that can be used with the `QMediaObject::metaData()` method.  So you want something more like

```
QDateTime t = mediaObject->metaData(QMediaMetaData::DateTimeOriginal).toDateTime();
```

Comment: Thanks. So i have to create a mediaObject? I already have the path as a string.

Comment: I don't know how to get a suitable `QMediaObject` from a filename or contents - I tried to find it hidden in there, but the Qt Multimedia seems more oriented towards building capture devices than for graphics editors.  :(